# Random text to be displayed in body of HTML

Tags: javascript, html, random

I want to insert a randomly selected piece of text into the page when it loads. The possible pieces of text are stored in an array within a function called `randomtext`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function randomtext() {
        var randomtxt=[
            'Beautiful People are not always Good but Good people are always Beautiful!',
            '50% + 50% off <a href="/offers.html">check here</a>',
            'New Arrivals <a href="/new.html">Click here<img src="http://mastimix.in/pictures/icon-new.gif"/></a>',
            'We changed our terms and conditions > <a href="my link"> check </a>'
        ];
        return randomtxt[Math.floor((Math.random() * 3.99))];
    }
</script>
```

Now I want to display any one of the line randomly whenever the page is loaded or refreshed inside the `<body>` tag, or any particular area I want to place the line.

Now tell me what to write there in `<body>` tag?

Comment: Show us code you already have, and we'll guide you, otherwise craigslist is full of coders for rent.

Comment: I dont have any codes till now. I want to display randomly my lines in the body tag whenever called!

Comment: Here's a beginner javascript tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/js/DEFAULT.asp

Comment: @GarySchreiner coders on craigslist??? they must be posting for simple solutions on SO themselves. ... oh wait!!!

Comment: @Ejay lol! I've seen that happen as well! When somebody asks how to do some basic code for their "client."

Comment: "Pl make a java function for me and tell me how to call it in the body tag." HA! SO isn't for asking others to do work for you. Pay someone for that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/).

Comment: @JasonAller I'm stealing your comment for future use if you don't mind. Could have used that on a question yesterday.

Comment: Any one could help me please?

Comment: You can't just ask people to write the entire code for you. That's not a question, that's an ask. If you don't know how to code, pay someone to or learn. You can't expect others to do it for free.

Comment: @Munna You don't want help, you want the work done for you. Use the link I posted above with the basic JavaScript tutorial and learn. Try some code, then come back here and post what problems you're having. I'd rather teach you to fish then hand you one.

Comment: Ok let me modify my question

Comment: pl guide me now or edit my function written above

Comment: Munna, in your page do you load jQuery, or does your solution need to be one that uses pure JavaScript?

Comment: I need only JavaScript! Thank you.

Comment: It'd be a lot simpler with JQuery. I'll write something quick for you now.

Comment: first, you need to put a `]` after `3.99))`

Comment: My website/webpages are stored in a private hosting company. So I am unable to store .js files on their servers.

Comment: can you store .html or .php files on their server?

Comment: no, Only I can add a file and edit the source code

Comment: Can you add a new empty file named `j.js` and paste some code in it by editing source code?

Comment: no, That js file can be hosted elsewhere and and called by <script src="" >
Please help me with the above topic please. using java function and call-Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As you've worked to improve your question and you did have a working function for `randomText`. If you add a target to the HTML like `<p id="spam"></p>` and then add `document.getElementById("spam").innerHTML = randomtext();` it will display the output from your `randomtext` in the spam paragraph.

http://jsfiddle.net/qVf8G/

This code is using the native JavaScript methods for finding the spam paragraph `document.getElementById("spam")` and then addressing the content of it as `innerHTML` and assigning the random text to it.